Opamp inverting and non inverting issue
I want to get inverting and non inverting square wave at the same time. I am using EL2444 quad op amp, gain not required.
My input is approx. 550 kHz, 50% duty cycle square wave.
I assume that I will get the same output from non inverting op amp and inverted output from inverting op amp. But actually I am getting inverted output ok but non inverting output is differ, its duty factor was changed.
What should I do? Is there any problem in my circuit OR should I change op amp?

Fig.1: Non-inverting output (blue) and input (yellow)


Fig.2: Inverting output (blue) and input (yellow)


Fig.3: Circuit diagram


You don't need to build a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of higher than unity. Instead, just build a buffer (remove R4, and short R3 or leave it as it is). Also, show your setup including the oscilloscope, signal source and overall circuit connections.

U1.1 ( non inverting) has gain of 2, not 1.  Remove R4 (make it infinite ♾️). Be careful: confirm that U1.1 is unity-gain stable for non-inverting gain of +1.

It's unity gain stable upgraded version.

Thanks Fabio, It works now

The Non inverting amplifier is overdriven, because its amplification A=2.
Remove R4, so it will work as a buffer.

Thanks dear. it works now
